# Redirect back to the login page after logged in

Tags: php, laravel-5.7

I have created a custom login page and registration page, all works good but when I try to logged in it redirect me back to the login page without any errors.
Following is store method in SessionsController for login but it does'n work I don't know why can any one help?

```php
public function store()
{

    if(! auth()->attempt(request(['email','password'])))
    {

        return back();

    }
    return view('/posts');
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? If you just want to protect this route, you should just use the `auth` middleware.

Comment: Thank you Mozammil i have solved it.